# Retrieve data only once for two activities using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I'm new to Android development and currently (trying to) code an application  for a school related project.

I have some data stored in a Firebase Database that I retrieve using the onChildEvent() method, and I want to use this data in two Activities, one is a GoogleMap and the other is a List. My problem is, even though I have no particular problem retrieving the data, it seems to me that doing it twice for the same data is not the right way of doing it, but i can't help to find the appropriate solution.

I thought about retrieving the data in one of the activities and passing it to the other using an intent, but since the two activities are not directly linked (no way and no reason of going from one to the other), I don't think this is a good idea.

PS: English isn't my native language, if anything isn't clear, just ask and I'll do my best to reformulate ;)

Comment: You can simply use singleton pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Dima Rostopira says, you could implement a Singleton, which exists once over the course of an application.

Example with "Location" object:

```
final class LocationModel {

    private Context mContext;

    /** List of locations */
    private ArrayList<Location> mLocations;

    /** Static instance of LocationModel, accessible throughout the scope of the applicaton */
    private static final LocationModel sLocationModel = new LocationModel();

    private LocationModel() {}

    /**
     * Returns static instance of LocationModel
     */
    public static LocationModel getLocationModel() {
        return sLocationModel;
    }

    /**
     * Sets context, allowed once during application
     */
    public void setContext(Context context) {
        if (mContext != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("context has already been set");
        }
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    /**
     * Asynchronously loads locations using callback. "forceReload" parameter can be
     * set to true to force querying Firebase, even if data is already loaded.
     */
    public void getLocations(OnLocationsLoadedCallback callback, boolean forceReload) {
        if (mLocations != null && !forceReload) {
            callback.onLocationsLoaded(mLocations);
        }
        // make a call to "callback.onLocationsLoaded()" with Locations when query is completed
    }

    /**
     * Callback allowing callers to listen for load completion
     */
    interface OnLocationsLoadedCallback {
        void onLocationsLoaded(ArrayList<Locations> locations);
    }
}
```

Usage inside of an Activity:

```
MainActivity implements OnLocationsLoadedCallback {

...

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    LocationModel.getLocationModel().getLocations(this);

    ...
}


@Override
public void onLocationsLoaded(ArrayList<Locations> location) {
    // Use loaded locations as needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be exactly what I was searching for ! (and I can already tell you that the example saved me a lot of time :D)

Comment: Pew, I'm having a problem implementing the getLocations method... My problem is, how can I know my query is completed ? Because adding callback.onLocationLoaded(mLocations) after the addChildEventListener() effectively doesn't work... (Sorry for the stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere...)

Comment: And also, will does this solution work with realtime data ? Because the data stored in my Firebase Database is dynamic (users can edit it) and I would like to have access to the last information when I use it

Comment: @Nap you could change the callback to be called every time a child is loaded and just add the objects as they are loaded, so instead of something like "OnObjectsLoadedListener", which requires a complete list of children, you could have a listener that you call on each addChildEventListener.

Comment: I think I understand better now and the first solution suits perfectly what I want to do, but I still can't find a way of making a call to callback.onLocationsLoaded() **after** having retrieved the data, since Firebase data is retrieved asynchronously and I don't know much about AsyncTasks...

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother but I again tried to make this work but I just can't... Can you explain me how exactly I can "make a call to "callback.onLocationsLoaded()" with Locations when query is completed" It would help a lot.